# Groupie RecyclerView clicking specific item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclick

Could somebody explain to me how to click a specific item in RecyclerView using Groupie and Kotlin?
For now, I would like to display the username of the user clicked after clicking one of these buttons.
I tried this way, but nothing shows up in logcat:

```
package com.example.boxes.screens.addfriends

import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import com.example.boxes.R
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.xwray.groupie.Item
import com.xwray.groupie.ViewHolder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.invitation_row_invite.view.*

class InvitationItem (val invitation: Invitation): Item<ViewHolder>() {
    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.textview_friend_username.text = invitation.username

        viewHolder.itemView.invite_discard_button.setOnClickListener{ View.OnClickListener {
            Log.d("InvitationItem", it.textview_friend_username.toString())
        }}

        Picasso.get().load(invitation.userImageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.image_friend_avatar)
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.invitation_row_invite
    }

}
```

and this is the 
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Keg2b.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write just

```
viewHolder.itemView.invite_discard_button.setOnClickListener {
   Log.d("InvitationItem", invitation.username)
}
```

without `View.OnClickListener {}`. In your case you just create `View.OnClickListener` object if user click on button

Comment: Then I have a "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.widget.TextView.toString()' on a null object reference" error.

Comment: Oh, I spot mistake in my code and edit my answer.
The problem was in it.textview_friend_username.toString(). In this case it refers to ButtonView. We can fix this by just simple log invitation.username, which equals to textview_friend_username.text

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you also know how I can then make this OnClickListener start some function in ViewModel(some Firebase stuff)? How to handle it?

Comment: Sure. Usually I pass lambda to item constructor like this 
`class InvitationItem (val invitation: Invitation, val onInvitationClick: (Invitation) -> Unit) `


And after this you can use it in onBind method
`viewHolder.itemView.invite_discard_button.setOnClickListener {
   onInvitationClick(invitation) // Invoke lambda
}`
And you can set your ViewModel function when you create your item:
`val item = InvitationItem(invitation, { inv: Invitation -> viewModel.onInvitationClick(inv) } )`

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!